# Evaluating the sum using Taylor series

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, computational-mathematics

I want to find

$$\sum\limits_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{xe^{2x-5}5^x}{x!} $$

The book has this problem in says to use for the Taylor series of $e^x = \sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^j}{j!} $ . I then got no idea how the book came to a final answer of $4e^2$. Any help from anyone would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I'm not seeing any $i$'s in the sum. Is $x$ supposed to be $i$?

Comment: There's a messy confusion between the running index, the variable and etc.....Please correct that.

Comment: Yeah my apology for the typo. Now it's edited.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

1) First **huge hint**: change that awfully lookin  running index $\;x\;$ for $\;k,n,m\;$ or something similar.

2) Use the series for the exponential function with

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k\,3^{2k-5}5^k}{k!}=\frac1{e^5}\sum_{k=1}\frac{(5e^2)^k}{(k-1)!}$$